# Truth tables, boolean expressions and circuits

Tags: boolean-expression, circuit, digital-logic, truthtable

I have created my truth table and drawn from this a boolean expression (f = B'A' + CA' + DC' + DB + D'CB') which I have then attempted to convert into a circuit using Quartus.

I am new to digital logic and I need some help from someone wit experience who can tell me if what I have attempted looks correct.

I am unable to compile the circuit as I don't have 'device support installed'. If anyone could point me in the right direction for how to obtain that, that would be greatly appreciated.

This is the circuit I created based on the boolean expression.

[image]

This is my truth table. The circuit corresponds to the f column

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit?

Answer (score 0):

Everything to the left of your `AND` gates looks mathematically correct (although not very efficient). You can drastically reduce the amount of `NOT` gates used.

Instead of splitting the signals *before* the `NOT` gates and having each individual branch have its own `NOT` gate, you can split the signals *after* the `NOT` gate thus reducing the total amount of `NOT` gates used.

Anyway, the fundamental reason your circuit is invalid is because of the very right part of it, here:

[image]

You are shorting together the outputs of two gates, which is not allowed. A single node cannot simultaneously have two separate voltages.

What you need to do to fix this problem is take each individual output of your 5 `AND` gates and take them all to a separate input of a 5-input `OR` gate.

Something like this:

[image]

If this software package that you are using doesn't support five inputs to a gate, then you can split it up like so:

[image]